# How to make generic extends data class

Tags: kotlin, generics

I know I can do something like this:

```
interface ISpecialEnum{/*interace stuff*/}

fun <T> consumeSpecialEnum(enum: T)
        where T:Enum<T>, T:ISpecialEnum{
    //code
}
```

to force a function to accept only enums with a specific interface.

Is there anything in kotlin to check if a generic extends a data class? Like:

```
interface ISpecialDataClass{/*interface stuff*/}

fun <T> consumeSpecialDataClass(dataClass: T)
        where T:DataClass<T>, T:ISpecialDataClass{
    //code
}
```

Comment: Ps: hope the extends interfaces don't confuse any people, I just want to know if it extends a data class, never mind the interface

Comment: You say you want to see if it extends a data class, but your example looks like you want to enforce that only a data class can be passed to this function. Which do you want?

Comment: @Tenfour04 check not by `if then else`, but by `T extends DataClass` which should throw a compile type error (unless unchecked casts on erased types are used and then runtime errors are thrown). To answer your question both.

Comment: There is no compile-time check to enforce that the type represents a data class.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your type T is a data class (and that it implements your interface) like so:

```
fun <T> func(param : T) where T : ISpecialInterface {
    if (param::class.isData) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

If you only want to check if it's a data class, you should remove the 'where' clause, however, to ensure that the type T cannot be null, you need to replace `fun <T>` with `fun <T : Any>`, as just `<T>` defaults to `<T : Any?>`.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast with enums, there is no common supertype for all data classes (excluding `Any`, which is a common supertype for absolutely all kotlin classes).
So, generally, this check can't be done in compile time (but it is possible in runtime via [reflection API](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/is-data.html)).